# android app running multiple instances

Tags: android, google-play

When i download my app from store.
its installed on main screen, and on apps menu ( when i click the circle with 6 dots on it  )

when i click from main screen it opens an app, and when i click from the other place..it opens a second app as well. 
i need one app running only..
how can this be fixed?

my manifest

```
   <application
    android:name="dfsfsdp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".StartupActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: its happening on nexus 4 kitkat.

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't running multiples instances (if you are running multiple instances if fail of the mobile), or you see two applications open in the menu what you use to close the running apps (the recent applications menu)?

If you only see one maybe your are restarting the same instance. Look at your StartupActivity or post here to try help you.

If this don't help you, take a look at to read about the lifecycle of an Activity:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Best regards.

Comment: Assume I clicked on the app from the launcher ( shortcut), it opens the app. I click on the launcher (shortcut ) again it redirects me to same place i am. But if i go to the app drawers, and click my application from there...a second app is running.

Comment: assume i delete the shortcut downloaded from app store. create the shortcut by myself from the drawer. When I run app from launcher, it opens goes to activity 6 ( from 1 to 6)..then when i click on my app from the drawer..it redirects me back to 6 rightly so.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brcreativity.gulfjobs&hl=en try this app for example. download it. i click on shortcut from launcher, then i go to click it from drawer... i have to click back twice now to close the app. two same activities open. this issue is on many apps in android kitkat, but important apps like Facebook linkedin gmail all handled it well.

Comment: Then I cant help you, i didn't find info for your issue.